# Дочерний компонен в VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как использовать в родительском компоненте `methods` и `watch` дочернего?

Есть компонент `A` и `B`, и общий компонент `Watch`

```
// компонент A
import Watch from '@/components/Watch'
export default {
  components: {watch: Watch},
  name: 'a',
  data () {
    return {
      login: ''
    } 
  },
  methods: {}
}

// компонент B
import Watch from '@/components/Watch'
export default {
  components: {watch: Watch},
  name: 'b',
  data () {
    return {} 
  },
  methods: {}
}

// компонент Watch
export default {
  name: 'Watch',
  data () {
    return {} 
  },
  methods: {
  // логика которую нужно использовать в родительских компонентах 
  },
  watch: {
   // логика которую нужно использовать в родительских компонентах 
  }
}
```

Решил таким образом. Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но работает.

```
import Watch from '@/components/Watch'
    export default {
      component: {Watch},
      name: 'a',
      data () {
        return {} 
      },
      methods: {},
      watch: {
        'login': function (value) {
           // Watch компонент, watch опция, isLogin метод
           this.login = Watch.watch.isLogin(value);
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: А как вы подключаете компоненты? Приложите верстку

Comment: У компонента Watch нет верстки, он подключается только в родительские компонент. В версте родительского компонента он не вызывается.

Comment: То есть вы его подключаете, но не используете? Значит вопрос некорректен. Компонент - это как класс, и в вашем случае вы как бы подключаете класс, но ни одного инстанса, которому можно было бы подёргать методы, у вас нет...

Comment: Может вам нужен не компонент а [миксин](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Наследование в VueJS аналогично наследованию обычных объектов javascript. Доступ к методам родительского компонента возможно получить через контекст дочернего, грубо говоря через `this`. Однако родительский компонент не может получить доступ к дочернему. В этой статье описаны варианты [взаимодействия компонентов](https://medium.com/@modex13/vue-js-2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-467383294847)

Comment: Это статья замечательная, но в данном случае она мне помочь не может. Ловить событие и писать функцию для ее отлова в моем случае почти эквивалентно количеству кода в дочернем компоненте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно организовать доступ через [$refs](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Только в watch это не будет работать ($refs не реактивны)